# Force expression to constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

Given the two `constexpr` functions, is it possible to combine them into one function?

```
template <char... C>
constexpr int boo()
{
    char ch[] = { C... };
    int count = 0;

    for (char c : ch)
    {
        if (c != '0') count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}

template <char... C>
constexpr auto foo()
{
    std::array<char, boo<C...>()> x{};

    return x;
}
```

As the example shows I can return '`count`' as a constant.
My problem is I can't use '`count`' as a constant in the function it's declared.  That is if the body of '`boo()`' is placed in '`foo()`', the compiler throws up with '`count`' not being a constant.

Comment: Why do you want it to be constexpr in the function? It cant be constant, it changes.

Comment: Yet boo can return it as a constant.  I just thought there would be a way to do it without needing two constexpr functions.

Comment: That's just how the language works. Function parameters and non-`constexpr` local variables can't be compile-time constants.

Comment: Your code works fine here in C++14 mode. Can it be you're still using C++11?

Comment: The code works but my attempts at combining them isn't.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could actually see the code you've omitted.

Comment: @NikosC., `constexpr i = 0; i += 1; std::array<int, i> array;`.

Comment: @NikosC. the only code I've omitted is `auto a= foo<'0','1','2','0'>();` in main()

Comment: @Evg - `i += 1` would be ill-formed. There's no way the OP omitted something like that.

Comment: Obviously the compiler has no problem returning `count` from `boo()` as a constant, thought there would be a trick to let me use it as a constant within the same function.

Comment: @StoryTeller, it was my supposition about what OP wanted to do (effectively) by pasting the `boo`'s body into the `foo`'s one. On the one hand, `i` has to be a `constexpr` to be used as a template parameter, on the other hand it is to be modified somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `std::array` needs a constant as size value.

If you define `count` and modify it inside `foo()`, `count` (as seen inside the `foo()` function) is a variable, not a constant.

So you need to modify it in another place: in a `constexpr` function, so the returned value become a compile-time known constant.

If you can use C++17, so template folding (with improvement from Evg and Rakete1111; thanks), you can avoid `bar()` at all

```
template <char... C>
constexpr auto foo()
{
    std::array<char, (0u + ... + (C != '0'))> x{};

    return x;
}
```

but if you have only C++11, you need recursion

```
template <typename = void>
constexpr std::size_t bar ()
 { return 0u; }

template <char C0, char ... C>
constexpr std::size_t bar ()
 { return bar<C...>() + (C0 == '0' ? 0u : 1u); }

template <char... C>
constexpr std::array<char, bar<C...>()> foo()
 { return {}; }
```

Comment: I'd use `0 + ... + ` for genericity. Parameter pack can be empty, and `std::array` can have zero size.

Comment: Also you can use `C != '0'` instead of the conditional operator

Comment: The pre-C++17 solution still uses another function template, though.

Comment: @Evg - good point; I'm used to template folding with `&&` and `||` where isn't necessary but you're right: with a sum is important.

Comment: While I'm aware of this I thought there would be a way of merging the two function bodies.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I'm in doubt if, for didactic reasons, is better use an explicit ternary operator but... it's C++... yes... `+ (C != '0')` should be comprehensible to anyone.

Comment: @Acorn - yes, but without variables in it (that are forbidden in C++11 `constexpr` functions).

Comment: @Rlyeh - I don't see a way, before C++17: if the `count` variable is modified inside `foo()`, it's a variable (strictly speaking) and not a constant; and the size for a `std::array` needs a constant. So you need to modify `count` in another `constexpr` function (or expression, as in C++17).

Answer (score 4):

For C++14 and up, if your goal is to "merge" the bodies, you could simply define a type inside your function template:

```
template <char... C>
constexpr auto foo()
{
    struct {
        constexpr int operator()() {
            char ch[] = { C... };
            int count = 0;

            for (char c : ch)
            {
                if (c != '0') count += 1;
            }

            return count;
        };
    } boo;

    std::array<char, boo()> x{};

    return x;
}
```

If you have C++17, you can also use lambdas in constant expressions, so you can shorten `boo` to:

```
constexpr auto boo = []() { /* ... */ };
```

In C++20, you will be able to write lambda expressions directly as a template argument, so you could reduce further to (if you *really* wanted it):

```
std::array<char, []() { /* ... */ }()> x{};
```

Having said that, in general, I would say that the usual (and cleaner) approach to have all kinds of extra code used by templates in a header but that are not part of the public interface is putting them in a `detail` or similarly named namespace:

```
namespace detail {
    template <char... C>
    constexpr int boo()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

template <char... C>
constexpr auto foo()
{
    /* ... detail::boo<C...>() ... */
}
```

Comment: @Evg Added it, plus also a mention to yet another way in C++20 to further shorten it.